# Visual Studio WinForm Designer not working after .Net Framework migration to .Net Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, devexpress, designer

Hello StackOverFlow residents,

We migrated our giant enterprise project from **.Net Framework -> .Net Core 6**. The Xaml WCF Designer **works just fine**, while the **WinForm** and **old Report designers** are **not** working.

What steps should I follow?
Thanks.

Winform Designer
[image]
Xaml Designer
[image]
Old Reports Designer
[image]
New Reports Designer

A few steps I tried:

I created an external project independent of my project and tested whether the designer works in the same sdk version. The **designer worked** on the new project.
I added a new form in the project where the designer is not working and tested whether the designer works. **Failed**.

I think this is due to a setting or something in the visual studio solution since I switched from .Net Framework -> .Net Core.

Comment: I had similar problems when migrating and it was because I didn't have the correct SDK installed

Comment: I checked my dotnet sdk versions

There is the results
.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.409 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

I migrate all project to .net6 and .net6-windows.  Which version should i use? Already have .net 6 equivalent.

Comment: Hey Jiale Xue. We are refactored all csproj xmls and WinForm designer fixed. But report designer still bugged out and giving error for System.Runtime.Configuration.Primitives.

Comment: We fixed that error tho, you should reopen report and change bindings to expression binding. Old .net framework reports designers class does not have  this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container(); section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all programs can be switched through a simple .Net Framework->.Net Core.

For project upgrades, there is a complete migration tutorial. Here's the relevant material: [Example of migrating to the latest .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modernize-desktop/example-migration)

Your non-working program may be due to an unsupported environment, try following the tutorial to migrate your program.